# On Ubuntu Linux 16.04, what file is the Apache2 AcceptMutex directive currently set in?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

On Ubuntu Linux 16.04, what file is the Apache2 AcceptMutex directive currently set in? The reason we need to know this is to create the LockFile necessary to create additional VirtualHosts such as apache2_00n where n = 1,2,3...

I was wondering if it is necessary to create extra Virtual hosts to handle Apache HTTP requests from different root directories such as /var/www/firstaspnet serviced by a single mod_mono_server4 process. Can we do that in a production environment without a C# compiler such as dmcs?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oracle Fusion Middleware Administrator's Guide for Oracle HTTP Server 11g Release 1(11.1.1)  E10144-05 November 2011, Section 4.4.8 page 4-17,the Apache2 AcceptMutex directive is included in the /etc/httpd.conf file.

Comment: Apache actually doesn't care into which file you put your directives, the main concern is the context they are in. `AcceptMutex` is only valid in the server (global) context and so it can be anywhere as long as it isn't inside a `<VirtualHost>`, `<Directory>` block, or in an `htaccess` file. Expanded explanation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context